# Preposition "of" used after noun/pronoun in the middle of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

Would the use of the preposition "of" in the middle of the following sentence (I imagine I'm using the passive voice for emphasis) be acceptable?

> That's the only way you know X (of) because you're not familiarized with Y

where X is the noun/pronoun, and Y would be the rest of the sentence.

I do understand that in many cases, usage of "of" would not be necessary and the sentence would just be valid (that's why I wrote the preposition between parentheses), however when used as a figure of speech or for dramatic purposes/emphasis, like in:

> The only way you know me of is through violence

As in, the only way you got to know about "me", or so that "me" in the sentence was only heard "through violence". Would that be correct? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean to put the "(of)" _after_ X? Because I cannot think of an example of that which would be grammatical. Certainly _The only way you know me of is through violence_ is not grammatical, in any variety of English that I can think of. Or did you mean _by_? _The only way you know me by is ..._ is grammatical, though awkward.

Comment: As Colin Fine suggests, we say "you know **of** X", not "you know X of", so it's not clear why you want to put *of* after *X*.

Comment: Unless you can explain why you think that placing "of" there might be acceptable, I don't see why this question would be on-topic.

Comment: "of" is a preposition, which means it has to have a noun complement. Do you think "because" is a noun?

Comment: No.  You can't use "of" in those sentences. It doesn't make sense.